# Are all Alicorns Royal?

Tags: my-little-pony-fim, my-little-pony, genealogy, unicorns

All the Princess' in the My Little Pony, Friendship is Magic series have both wings and a horn. Is this a trend, or a coincidence? I suppose I want to know, which one implies the other? Are they royal due to their alicorn nature, or are they only alicorns because they belong to the royal blood line?

Comment: Someone's getting antsy for the next season of MLP :)

Comment: I suppose there is a direct correlation between coronation and ascension to alicorn, like, by ascending you prove yourself worthy of the crown. It's not the wings and the horn that give you the title, it's more like they are a part of your regalia; I guess an ascended alicorn could refuse the title or abdicate later, but it's the fact you ascended that proves you worthy, and the extra appendages are just a bonus. Also note all changelings have wings and horns but only one holds a royal title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spoiler for season 3 finale :

> Yes, though princesses are not born this way, they become an Alicorn as they become a princess.
>
>  In the [season 3 finale](http://mlp.wikia.com/wiki/Magical_Mystery_Cure), Twilight Sparkle magically becomes an Alicorn.
>
>  [image: Twilight Sparkle as an Alicorn]
>
>  *"The others marvel at Twilight's new look, Fluttershy commenting that she looks just like a princess. Princess Celestia appears and says Twilight **is a princess**, explaining that since arriving in Ponyville, she's displayed the charity, compassion, devotion, integrity, optimism, and leadership that a true princess is known for."*
>
>  She is crowned the next day as Equestria's newest princess.
>
>  [image: Twilight's coronation]

Answer (score 3):

In general, the answer so far is "we don't know much about it" because we've only seen <s>two</s> three alicorns as of yet on the show. I have little doubt they'll cover the subject more in a future episode (it's one of the relative few glaring bits of history/Equestria they haven't gotten to explaining yet), but for now...

Comment: Never mind about that last sentence, i get what you're saying now (all alicorns are royal but not all royals are alicorns vs all royals are alicorns but not all alicorns are royal)

Comment: IIRC, Faust's original intent was for Celestia and Luna to be unique in the setting ("winged unicorns" at that time, not "alicorns"). However, the lore has expended since Faust's original vision, so "we don't really know" is definitely the correct answer for now.

Answer (score 3):

Prince Blueblood, it may be noted, was not.  So likely no, it's just an inherent trait.  What I'd like to know is how the alicorn "gene" as it may be, passes through the royal family.  Let's break this down over-analytically:

Cadence is Celestia's niece, which means likely a third Alicorn sibling, as it's unlikely Luna ever had children.  Blueblood is not an alicorn, but part of the royal family, meaning that the gene may be by-chance recessive or dominant.  I don't if that would really work... were there, then, four siblings, three female and one male (the wing gene being dominant in one gender?)

Feel free to downvote.  That made no sense, even to me.

Comment: In _Twilight Sparkle and the Crystal Heart Spell_ (April 2013), Cadence reveals that she was born a pegasus, and was later adopted by Celestia as her niece.